# \write command generates "incomplete \iffalse" error

Tags: write

I'm using LaTeX to generate a 100 pages document. Every page is basically a different randomly generated identity. At the end of every page, I use the `\write` command to write some datas that I generated in an external document.

When the compiler executes the command `\immediate\write\Query{\Name}%`, though, I receive the error `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 3002`. Error which I don't receive if I just write `\Name` in the document.

I need to understand why this happens, and the issue here is that the `\Name` command that I used there is actually a quite complex and big command, that includes other commands I made, a lot of `\ifthenelse` commands, `\ifcase` ones, `\csname` and so on...

So, it's hard for me to understand exactly which part of this is giving such error.

Before I can build an MWE, so, it would be useful for me to know exactly what is the meaning of the aforementioned error. What does it mean that there is an incomplete `\iffalse`, and what usually generates such an event in a `\write` command?

Comment: It means that there was an `\iffalse`  and no matching `\fi` but usually the error is not that relevant it is just that Tex has gone wrong earlier and so is executing unintended code until it finally hits some more or less arbitrary error condition and stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the source of the "fragile command in a moving argument" errors and the `\protect` command in LaTeX.

If you want to write `\Name` to the file then it is simple:

```
\immediate\write\Query{\string\Name}%
```

If you want to write some version of the expansion of `\Name` then it's trickier, `\ifthenelse` for example does not work by expansion so will not expand to its true or false branch while expanding in a `\write`.

You may be able to use

```
  \protected@write
```

instead of `\write` depending on whether all the commands in the definition of `\Name` are robust.

Comment: Indeed, working around the `\ifthenelse` commands did the job. Thank you ;)